# Using jQuery to toggle a navbar, and if user engages navbar media queries stop working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navbar that is set to be hidden by default. There is a hamburger icon that, when clicked, engages some js/jquery to toggle between the navbar being hidden/showing.

I also have a media query that sets the navbar to always be showing on smaller screens, and to place the navbar to the top of the page where it is displayed as a row. My problem is that if I engage the navbar (toggle it to show, then toggle back to hide) my media query does not work, and the navbar never shows up when the breakpoint is hit.

Here's the code:

Navbar CSS, default state:

```
.navbar-hidden{
  grid-row-start: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 300px;
  display: none;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: 100%;
 }
```

JS/jQuery targeting the navbar:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#menu").click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $(".navbar-hidden").toggle();
 })
});
```

Media query that targets the navbar-hidden (which should now always show) after a breakpoint:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .navbar-hidden {
    display: show !important;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-column-start: 2;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    font-size: 3em;
    min-width: 100%;
  }
```

Comment: {display: none;}
{display: inline;}
{display: block;}
{display: inline-block;}
I don't know any {display: show}
Change to display: block on your css, lets try it.

Comment: Two “display” property within the same class? And why naming the class “hidden” if the display property is set to “show” (which doesn’t exist AFAIK)?